# incorrect git history and git blame in idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

From time to time it happens to me, that shown git blame is different from what I can see using pure git commands. Now I even see totally wrong commits in branches in git tool window — multiple branches has different commits, including ones which does not actually exist if I compare it to output of tig.

refresh icon in tool window does not help. Reload all from disk does not help. Invalidate everything and realoading IDE -- cured.

OK, great, it has 'solution'. but WHY does it happen in first place? How to prevent it / notice it sooner/automatically, since I *can* work with confused IDE and prepare some unpleasant work with reflog. This time I lost only 5 minutes untio I confirmed idea is wrong, and luckily no damage was done.

Or is there a workaround? This is clearly a bug in cache. Can we disable it here? I mean -- loading it via tig etc. takes approximately 10 miliseconds. I can spare those to get always correct result.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-232.8660.185, built on July 26, 2023
Licensed to ....
Expiration date: October 7, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+7-b1000.6 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.19.0-45-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    net.sf.opk.avro-schema-support (213.5.2)
    org.turbanov.run.configuration.as.action (1.5.1)
    org.jetbrains.plugins.go-template (232.8660.88)
    com.intellij.kubernetes (232.8660.158)
    String Manipulation (9.10.0)
    PlantUML integration (6.3.1-IJ2023.2)
    org.asciidoctor.intellij.asciidoc (0.38.20)
    com.dmarcotte.handlebars (232.8660.88)
    net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (3.2.1-232)
    MetricsReloaded (1.12)

Kotlin: 232-1.9.0-IJ8660.185
Current Desktop: X-Cinnamon
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to git indexing issues. Can you please try to update to 2023.2.2?

It should be handled much better in the newer versions.